# Treecontrol: SelectionChanged Event called thrice

Tags: c#

I have a tree control used in my form and have around 10 items in the tree. 
Each Parent having one sub child/node.

I am handling the SelectionChanged event of the tree. Whenever an treeitem is selected this event is fired and the function called. But this function is called at least thrice!!

Is there something that i have done wrong where everytime i select a tree item it is called thrice !!

Comment: it will be more clear if you post some of code.

Answer (score 0):

r u doing something in the handler which causes tree selection event to fire ?

Can you please post some of your code?

**EDIT**

try putting e.Handeled = true in your handler

Comment: No, in the handler i am just checking for some condition and changing the text of a label control.

Comment: than ru using  use e.handeled = true in the handler?